# Passport calls deserializeUser for every request with NextJs and Express

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, next.js

I'm implementing a simple login for my node app with Passport Local, Express, Next.js, and MongoSession store.

Everything works well, except my app runs deserializeUser for every single request. This results in my db being hit 10+ times for any app interaction

Based on this post https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/14#issuecomment-4863459 I know that my requests for static assets are hitting the middleware stack.

Most of the requests are for the path /_next/static*

I have tried and failed to implement express.static as shown in the above example. Please help me figure out how avoid calling deserializeUser on every request.

Thanks!

Here's my code:

app.js

```
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = express();
  server.use(helmet());
  server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '_next', 'static')));
  server.use(express.json());

  auth({ ROOT_URL, server });
  api(server);

  routesWithSlug({ server, app });
  sitemapAndRobots({ server });

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const url = URL_MAP[req.path];
    if (url) {
      app.render(req, res, url);
    } else {
      handle(req, res);
    }
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    logger.info(`> Ready on ${ROOT_URL}`);
  });
});

module.exports = { app };
```

auth.js

```
function auth({ ROOT_URL, server }) {
  const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';


  const MongoStore = mongoSessionStore(session);

  const sess = {
    name: 'builderbook.sid',
    secret: process.env.sessSecret,
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60, // expires in 14 days
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // expires in 14 days
    },
  };

  if (!dev) {
    server.set('trust proxy', 1);
    sess.cookie.secure = true;
  }

  server.use(session(sess));
  server.use(passport.initialize());
  server.use(passport.session());
  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('serializeUser');
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    console.log(`deserializeUser, id: ${id}`);
    User.findById(id, User.publicFields(), (err, user) => {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

  const verifyLocal = async (req, email, password, done) => {
    console.log({ email, password, req });
    const { firstName, lastName } = req.body;
    try {
      // signInOrSign up the user to MongoDb
      const user = await User.signInOrSignUp({
        email,
        password,
        firstName,
        lastName,
      });
      console.log(user);

      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      if (!User.verifyPassword(email, password)) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err); // eslint-disable-line
      return done(err);
    }
  };


  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passReqToCallback: true,
      },
      verifyLocal,
    ),
  );
}

module.exports = auth;
```

authroutes.js

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/fail' }), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 4):

This code seemed to solve the problem. Thanks to Tima over at Builderbook!

https://github.com/builderbook/builderbook/issues/229

```
server.get('/_next*', (req, res) => {
    handle(req, res);
  });

  server.get('/static/*', (req, res) => {
    handle(req, res);
  });
```